# Mockserver: Expectation de archivo pdf desde archivo de expectaciones .json

Tags: testing, mockserver

Estoy utilizando Mockserver (Desde docker) para simular la parte de infraestructura de mi aplicacion, que llama a un servicio remoto. Dicho servicio remoto me devuelve un pdf.

Estoy tratando de configurar una expectacion de llamada al servicio, para que me devuelva un pdf de ejemplo, y asi pasar el test de aceptacion.

En el archivo de configuracion de mockserver he puesto lo siguiente:

```
{
    "httpRequest": {
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/api/v1/documentos/57886",
        "body": {
            "data": {
                "foo": "bar",
                "bar": "foo"
            }
        }
    },
    "httpResponse": {
       "statusCode": 200,

       "headers": [
           {
               "name": "Content-Type",
               "values": ["application/pdf"]
           },
           {
               "name": "Content-Description",
               "values":["File Transfer"]
           },
           {
               "name": "Content-Disposition",
               "values": ["attachment;filename=informe.pdf"]
           },
           {
               "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
               "values": ["binary"]
           }

       ]
    }
},
```

y en el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo de definiciones, he añadido un pdf de ejemplo con el nombre `informe.pdf`

El servidor mockserver, cuando lo reinicio, me dice que todas las espectaciones son correctas. El tema es que, cuando hago la llamada por postman, y le doy a la opcion de descargar, responde correctamente PERO el archivo llega con tamaño 0.

Entiendo que mockserver no esta encontrando el archivo en el directorio, pero he estado mirando en la documentacion oficial y no aparece informacion sobre en que directorio deberia estar (o como hacer referencia a ese archivo en la expectacion).

Alguien ha trabajado con este caso y puede orientarme?

Comment: Y porqué tener un fichero en un directorio y no crear uno al vuelo para enviarlo en cada petición? Total es un servidor de pruebas, no necesitas "probar" que se lea el directorio, sólo necesitas que te responda con un PDF. De dónde lo saca no es parte de la prueba, o me equivoco?.

Comment: entiendo que es mejor crearlo al vuelo. El tema es como indicarlo en la espectacion, en el archivo de las espectaciones. Solo he visto como crearlo a partir de codigo, pero no a partir de la definicion en el archivo. Por eso el intentar configurarlo desde un archivo.